# How to make Ubuntu automatically detect "Always connected" DSL connection?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

Ubuntu is not detecting my internet connection automatically. It is a DSL connection that is always online. How to make Ubuntu detect it automatically?

I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: And how would you be connecting to that DSL service?  Please name hardware and connection technologies used.

Comment: Hardware is: Motorola Modem [SurfBoard Model: SB5101U], TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DSL service provider (or ISP) does not require a login procedure, then it is quite possible there is no special "DSL Setup" that needs to be done (i.e. ignore the "DSL" tab in the "Network Connections" manager).

If you are running a wired connection from the model to your PC, then you should configured things under the "Wired" tab.  (The settings will be dependent on your ISP, but most likely setting it to use DHCP is the right solution.)